# HTML button action not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari

I'm running a web page in Safar, however; I notice that when I press the save button the event doesn't fire. It works fine in IE though. I've researched the issue, and found that it's not due to a missing value attribute or single/double quote specifics. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<input type='button' name='Save' id='saveCut' value='Save Cut' class=button onClick=\"Puma.saveTheCut()\">
```

JS function

```
Puma.saveTheCut = function () {
    var offerId = inStoreCut.cutOfferFields[0];
    var merchId = inStoreCut.cutOfferFields[1];
    var adId = inStoreCut.cutOfferFields[2];
    var eventID = inStoreCut.cutOfferFields[3]; 
    var adNum = inStoreCut.cutOfferFields[4]; 
    var cutID = inStoreCut.cutOfferFields[5];  


    var merchDescription = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchDescription').value;
    var UPC = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchUPC').value;

    var nrfSampleColorObj = parent.main.document.getElementById('itemColor');
    var nrfSampleColor = nrfSampleColorObj.options[nrfSampleColorObj.selectedIndex].value;

    var nrfsampleSubColorObj = parent.main.document.getElementById('itemChildColor');
    var colorCodeStr = nrfsampleSubColorObj.options[nrfsampleSubColorObj.selectedIndex].value;

    var nrfsampleSubColor = colorCodeStr.substring(0, 3);

    var customer_Facing_Color = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchCustomerFacingColor').value;


    var division = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchFob').value;
    var deptNum = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchDept0~0').value;
    var vendorNum = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchVendorNum0~0').value;
    var pID = parent.main.document.getElementById('pID0~0').value;

    var regPrice = parent.main.document.getElementById('regPrice').value;
    var sampleSize = parent.main.document.getElementById('itemSize').value;
    var itemQty = parent.main.document.getElementById('itemQty').value;
    if (parent.main.document.getElementById('chkMerchSet').checked) {
        var set = "1";
    }
    else {
        var set = "0";
    }

    var sampleTypeObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("itemType");
    var sampleType = sampleTypeObj.options[sampleTypeObj.selectedIndex].text;


    var merchColorCorrObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("merchColorCorr");
    var colorCorr = merchColorCorrObj.options[merchColorCorrObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var merchSwatchObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("merchSwatch");
    var Swatch = merchSwatchObj.options[merchSwatchObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var pantoneColor = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchPantone').value;
    var photoStylingDetails = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchPhotoStylingDetails').value;
    var mCOMSampleId = parent.main.document.getElementById('mCOMSample').value;

    var deptName = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchDeptName0~0').innerHTML;
    var vendorName = Puma.decoder(parent.main.document.getElementById('merchVendorName0~0').innerHTML);

    if (parent.main.document.getElementById('pidStatus0~0').value == "NOT IN PD") {
        var pidStatus = "0";
    }
    else {
        var pidStatus = "1";
    }
    var pidDescription = parent.main.document.getElementById('pidDescription').value;
    var webId = parent.main.document.getElementById('webID0~0').innerHTML;
    var vStyle = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchVStyle').value;
    var markStyle = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchMarkStyle').value;
    var subClass = parent.main.document.getElementById('Subclass').value;
    // var productDescription = parent.main.document.getElementById('productDescription').value;
    var docLineitemNum = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchDoc').value;

    var merchTurnInStatusObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("merchTurnInStatus");
    var turnInStatus = merchTurnInStatusObj.options[merchTurnInStatusObj.selectedIndex].text;
    var reason = parent.main.document.getElementById('merchReason').value;
    var merchCountryOriginObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("countryOfOrigin");
    var countryOfOrigin = merchCountryOriginObj.options[merchCountryOriginObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var importedCountry = parent.main.document.getElementById("importedCountries").value;
    //var importedCountry = merchImportedCountryObj.options[merchImportedCountryObj.selectedIndex].text;
    var fabricContent = parent.main.document.getElementById("fabricContent").value;
    var careInstructions = parent.main.document.getElementById("careInstructions").value;
    var offerDescription = parent.main.document.getElementById("offerDescription").value;
    var onlyAtMacysObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("onlyAtMacys");
    var onlyAtMacysValue = parseInt(onlyAtMacysObj.options[onlyAtMacysObj.selectedIndex].value, 10);
    var onlyAtMacys = onlyAtMacysValue;

    var legalOneObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("legalOne");
    var legalOne = legalOneObj.options[legalOneObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var legalOneExplain = parent.main.document.getElementById("explainLegalOne").value;
    var legalTwoObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("legalTwo");
    var legalTwo = legalTwoObj.options[legalTwoObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var legalTwoExplain = parent.main.document.getElementById("explainLegalTwo").value;
    var legalThreeObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("legalThree");
    var legalThree = legalThreeObj.options[legalThreeObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var legalThreeExplain = parent.main.document.getElementById("explainLegalThree").value;
    var legalFourObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("legalFour");
    var legalFour = legalFourObj.options[legalFourObj.selectedIndex].value;

    var fiftyObj = parent.main.document.getElementById("overFifty");
    var fifty = fiftyObj.options[fiftyObj.selectedIndex].value;
    var userId = parent.botnav.uinfo.userID;

    if (Puma.btiRequiredFieldIsValidated() == true) {
        if (inStoreCut.existingRecord == false) {
            sql = "action=saveMerchFormForCut&cutID=" + cutID +
               //sql = "action=updateMerchFormForCut&cutID=" + cutID +
              "&merchDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(merchDescription) +
              "&UPC=" + UPC +
              "&nrfSampleColor=" + nrfSampleColor +
              "&nrfSampleSubColor=" + nrfsampleSubColor +
              "&division=" + encodeURIComponent(division) +
              "&deptNum=" + deptNum +
              "&merchVendorNum=" + vendorNum +
              "&pID=" + pID +
              "&Customer_Facing_Color=" + encodeURIComponent(customer_Facing_Color) +
              "&regPrice=" + regPrice +
              "&sampleSize=" + encodeURIComponent(sampleSize) +
              "&itemQty=" + itemQty +
              "&set=" + set +
              "&sampleType=" + sampleType +
              "&colorCorr=" + colorCorr +
              "&Swatch=" + Swatch +
              "&pantoneColor=" + encodeURIComponent(pantoneColor) +
              "&photoStylingDetails=" + encodeURIComponent(photoStylingDetails) +
              "&mCOMSampleId=" + mCOMSampleId +
              "&deptName=" + deptName +
              "&vendorName=" + encodeURIComponent(vendorName) +
              "&pidStatus=" + pidStatus +
              "&pidDescription=" + pidDescription +
              "&webId=" + webId +
              "&vStyle=" + vStyle +
              "&markStyle=" + markStyle +
              "&subClass=" + subClass +
              "&docLineItemNum=" + docLineitemNum +
              "&merchTurnInStatus=" + turnInStatus +
              "&reason=" + encodeURIComponent(reason) +
              "&countryOfOrigin=" + countryOfOrigin +
              "&importedCountry=" + importedCountry +
              "&fabricContent=" + encodeURIComponent(fabricContent) +
              "&careInstructions=" + encodeURIComponent(careInstructions) +
              "&offerDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(offerDescription) +
              "&onlyAtMacys=" + onlyAtMacys +
              "&legalOne=" + legalOne +
              "&legalOneExplain=" + legalOneExplain +
              "&legalTwo=" + legalTwo +
              "&legalTwoExplain=" + legalTwoExplain +
              "&legalThree=" + legalThree +
              "&legalThreeExplain=" + legalThree +
              "&legalFour=" + legalFour +
              "&fifty=" + fifty +
              "&createdBy=" + userId

            var ajaxMaster = new AjaxMaster(sql, "Puma.saveMerchFormForCutData(data)", "", "btiDispatcher.aspx");


            sql = "action=updateMerchFormForCut&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(msql);
            objAjaxAd.main_flag = "updateMerchFormForCut";
            objAjaxAd.SendQuery(sql);
            // "[t0].[signedByUserID]," +
            // "[t0].[signedStatus]," +
            //"[t0].[dateSigned]," + 
            //"[t0].[signedLastByUserID]," +
            //"[t0].[dateLastSigned1]," +
            //"[t0].[signedLastStatus]" +


           // var ajaxMaster = new AjaxMaster(sql, "Puma.updateMerchFormForCutData(data)", "", "puma_core.aspx");
        }
        else {
            sql = "action=updateMerchFormForCut&cutID=" + cutID +
             "&offerId" + offerId +
             "&merchId" + merchId +
             "&adID" + adId +
             "&eventID" + eventID +
             "&adNum" + adNum +
             "&merchDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(merchDescription) +
             "&UPC=" + UPC +
             "&nrfSampleColor=" + nrfSampleColor +
             "&nrfSampleSubColor=" + nrfsampleSubColor +
             "&division=" + encodeURIComponent(division) +
             "&deptNum=" + deptNum +
             "&merchVendorNum=" + vendorNum +
             "&pID=" + pID +
             "&Customer_Facing_Color=" + encodeURIComponent(customer_Facing_Color) +
             "&regPrice=" + regPrice +
             "&sampleSize=" + encodeURIComponent(sampleSize) +
             "&itemQty=" + itemQty +
             "&set=" + set +
             "&sampleType=" + sampleType +
             "&colorCorr=" + colorCorr +
             "&Swatch=" + Swatch +
             "&pantoneColor=" + encodeURIComponent(pantoneColor) +
             "&photoStylingDetails=" + encodeURIComponent(photoStylingDetails) +
             "&mCOMSampleId=" + mCOMSampleId +
             "&deptName=" + deptName +
             "&vendorName=" + encodeURIComponent(vendorName) +
             "&pidStatus=" + pidStatus +
             "&pidDescription=" + pidDescription +
             "&webId=" + webId +
             "&vStyle=" + vStyle +
             "&markStyle=" + markStyle +
             "&subClass=" + subClass +
             "&docLineItemNum=" + docLineitemNum +
             "&merchTurnInStatus=" + turnInStatus +
             "&reason=" + encodeURIComponent(reason) +
             "&countryOfOrigin=" + countryOfOrigin +
             "&importedCountry=" + importedCountry +
             "&fabricContent=" + encodeURIComponent(fabricContent) +
             "&careInstructions=" + encodeURIComponent(careInstructions) +
             "&offerDescription=" + encodeURIComponent(offerDescription) +
             "&onlyAtMacys=" + onlyAtMacys +
             "&legalOne=" + legalOne +
             "&legalOneExplain=" + legalOneExplain +
             "&legalTwo=" + legalTwo +
             "&legalTwoExplain=" + legalTwoExplain +
             "&legalThree=" + legalThree +
             "&legalThreeExplain=" + legalThree +
             "&legalFour=" + legalFour +
             "&fifty=" + fifty +
            //"&createdBy=" + userId


            "&offerId=" + offerId +
            "&merchId=" + merchId +
            "&adID=" + adId +
            "&eventID=" + eventID +
            "&adNum=" + adNum
            var ajaxMaster = new AjaxMaster(sql, "Puma.updateMerchFormForCutData(data)", "", "btiDispatcher.aspx");



            sql = "action=updateMerchFormForCut&sql=" + encodeURIComponent(msql);

            //objAjaxAd.SendQuery(sql);
            // "[t0].[signedByUserID]," +
            // "[t0].[signedStatus]," +
            //"[t0].[dateSigned]," + 
            //"[t0].[signedLastByUserID]," +
            //"[t0].[dateLastSigned1]," +
            //"[t0].[signedLastStatus]" +
            objAjaxAd.main_flag = "updateMerchFormForCutData";

            objAjaxAd.SendQuery(sql);

            //var ajaxMaster = new AjaxMaster(sql, "Puma.updateMerchFormForCutData(data)", "", "puma_core.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `onclick` should be lower case and it should just be `onclick="Puma.saveTheCut()"`

Comment: If this the actual HTML code, as sent to a browser, then it should of course have just `"` and not `\"`, or you could just omit the quotation marks: `onClick=Puma.saveTheCut()`. If not, please post the *actual* code with which the problem can be reproduced. Naturally, we need minimally the `Puma.saveTheCut()` function definition, too.

Comment: `onClick` vs. `onclick` does not matter the least here.

Comment: @Jukka this is actual line of code. Puma.saveTheCut is just a JS function and shouldn't have any bearing on whether it works or not.

Comment: So the event doesn't fire when clicked, and you instantly omit the event in question?

Comment: add `console.log("something") or alert("something")` at the start of the function Puma.saveTheCut() to check whether the function is initiated or not ?

Comment: @Madhu13 That is built into the function, which indicates to me the function is being executed.

Comment: @Agony refer to my previous comment

Comment: For my mental sanity, @MasterP, look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/bEzBq/ I went out and got Safari (You better feel special) and just tested it.

Comment: @Agony I tested it as well, and it still does not fire in Safari

Comment: Can you share the code for the function? I'm about to call shenanigans on this whole operation you're running!

Comment: @Agony I added in the code to the original post.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/bEzBq/1/ Look at this one. I think it is something in your functions code.

Comment: @Agony could it be the missing RequiredValidation function at the bottom of the function?

Comment: I'll be honest, I didn't even look at it and I kind of don't want to. That's a lot of bacon and I am lazy :P I did check to make sure there weren't any missing `;`s though.

Comment: For a future question, please reduce the amount of code to the bare minimum that is required to reproduce the problem. This makes it more readable for someone that tries to answer your question and it helps you to figure out where in the code the problem lies, possibly eliminating the need to ask the question at all, because you already figured it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write just `"` and not `\"` in the `onClick` attribute, or just omit the quotation marks:

```
onClick=Puma.saveTheCut()
```

The character `\` has no special role in HTML; it’s just yet another character. So when you have `onClick=\"Puma.saveTheCut()\"`, the actual attribute value is `\"Puma.saveTheCut()\"`, which does not work of course, as you can see by looking at the console in the Developer Tools of your browser. You should see something the like following there:

```
SyntaxError: illegal character

\"Puma.saveTheCut()\"
```

(or with `\"yup()\"` when testing Agony’s jsfiddle).

As it is, the code should not work in any browser, and does not work in my IE 10 either.

Comment: The code does work in IE though.

Comment: @MasterP, then the HTML markup you are actually using is *not* what you included in the question – as I suspected, but you said it indeed is.